# Capturing Voice Chat on Xbox One & PS4

Tags: ps4, xbox-one, voice-chat

I'm a Twitch streamer and Youtube content creator. I use an Elgato capture card and I'm just starting out. When I did game capture with my Xbox 360, it was so much easier since the voice output went through the TV **and** my headset. Now If I plug a headset in, all chat is routed to the headset so I can't capture it with my capture card.

Is there a solid solution for capturing voice chat one the Xbox one and PS4 that doesn't require crazy hack job adapters and such?

Comment: Well, even though you stated no "hack job adapters", have you tried an audio splitter?

Comment: I haven't been able to find any that work without degrading the signal, noises etc...

Comment: Hmm... So, explain to me what you did on your XBox. Then tell me what you did on your PS4...

Comment: although you said you don't want "crazy hackjob adapters", [here's](https://help.elgato.com/customer/portal/articles/1569473-how-do-i-use-my-elgato-game-capture-hd-to-record-game-and-chat-audio-from-the-playstation-4-ps4-) a solution from Elgato themselves if you haven’t already seen it

Answer (score 1):

Twitch and YouTube uploading of game DVR is built in to the Xbox One. An Xbox One Stereo headset connector will cost around $30AU, and you can plug the headset/sound into the capture card using an RCA to 3.5mm converter and a headphone splitter(both cost around $5-10 in any discount store.

Comment: Twitch is built in. No hack jobs required. Enjoy.

Comment: I'll double check all this later today.

Comment: On the PS4, (from memory) you have to be friends with the other players and have them tick an option to allow their voice chat to be shared for the built in streaming to share other people's voice chat.